# Logging of handled exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I am developing a WPF .net 3.5 application which is using other modules/libraries created within a company. Not all of them support logging and sometimes the information about handled exceptions may be quite useful to find out what's wrong.
So the question is if I can get any notification or hookup somehow for handled events in other modules?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256548/is-there-a-way-to-log-or-intercept-first-chance-exceptions

Comment: It's not as easy as hooking an event, but there are ways to trap them.  Unfortunately it requires some pretty low-level hackery and may impact performance.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952304/net-first-chance-exception-listener-for-intensive-debugging

Comment: These questions make me wonder if there would be demand for a tool that would ildasm an assembly, list all locations where exceptions are swallowed and provide an automatic rewriter to inject a call to logging code (or even force the exception to rethrow for the purposes of debugging).  Sort of like AOP systems, but designed to work with unannotated DLLs as a way to deal with misbehaving third-party code.

Comment: The tool would be quite useful at least for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 5):

In net 4.0 and above, there is a solution:
The event [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) fires before any catch block is executed.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368.aspx) has some examples.

Basically you just add an event handler like this:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += 
        (object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two events, `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, which might help you. Otherwise, I think, you are out of luck, especially if the modules handle the exceptions themself. Only way would be to attach a debugger, as First-Chance exceptions show up there.

Comment: Unhandled can be caught and logged by my code. The question is really is about handled exceptions

Comment: Except for a debugger, you are out of luck.